# How to run flutter app in iOS devices from windows

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-run

I’m windows 11 system user, i have iPhone device (i11).

How we can run flutter app directly in iPhone device?

What is the best solution to development and test flutter application in android and ios in the same time (i have android/ios devices.

Ps: i don’t have money to buy mac, but i have a good pc: i7 11th generation, 16G ram.

Thank you

Comment: I know it sucks, but it is not possible at the moment. I am a Windows user too. :(

Comment: Your best option is to borrow/rent time on a mac. There are some online build systems that cater for this, such as codemagic: https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667

Comment: you can create a virtual machine for testing it you can test both on Mac virtual machine but not on windows

Comment: @UsamaAltaf so if i can build a macos in vm using windows?

Comment: @JigarPatel i thought that we can use something like react native hot

Comment: another option you can use with hackintosh in your pc/laptop.

Comment: @BrahimDjarallah yes you can build a mac vm machine in windows and start using mac it'll not be fast as actual mac machine obviously but yeah it'll work

Answer (score 3):

I know that you've been suggested to perhaps create a virtual machine with macOS installed on it on your hardware. However, according to macOS EULA it is in fact illegal to run macOS on non Apple-hardware unfortunately and you probably won't have so much luck getting the perfect hardware configuration on VM anyways!

Your best bet is to purchase a second hand Mac Mini which can solve your problem. If you temporarily need a Mac perhaps you could borrow one from a friend.

If you just need to build your application on macOS you could simply use a CI system such as CircleCI to build your application.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however i saw some articles about codemagic and travis to build my project (ci), but i want to know if i use cirlceCi or travis.. how can i test my application in my iPhone device ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Technically you cannot build an IPA file that you can later install on your Apple device directly from Windows.

**You have to use an external tool** like Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI). Odevio is a CLI utility that let you access a Mac build machine to generate an IPA that you can then install on your Iphone.

Here is an example demo : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX3DAMwlEfM&t=6s

Here is their full documentation to get you started : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_cli/tutorial_cli/6_configure_app_store_connect.html